# Replacing ButtonGroupPanel from com.symantec.itools.javax.swing package

Tags: java, swing, layout, buttongroup, null-layout-manager

I am  migrating 'Java Swing' code  from  'Java Visual Cafe' JDK1.2  to 'Eclipse SDK6'. In Visual Cafe  it has code is like this:

```
public  Sample extends JPanel(){
    .....
    package com.symantec.itools.javax.swing.JButtonGroupPanel  bgAcc = new com.symantec.itools.javax.swing.JButtonGroupPanel();
    ....
    bgAcc.setBorder(tbAcc);  //tbAcc  is titledBorder component  type
    ..
    bgAcc.setBounds(0,108,400,76);
    ...
    bgAcc.add(bgLb);     // bgLb  is  JLabel  component type
    ..
    bgAcc.add(button1, new GridBagConstraints(...));
    ..
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I can replace this code in Eclipse SDK6? I am unable find these methods for 'ButtonGroup' in 'Swing'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar wit the `JButtonGroupPanel` class, but those methods you use are all available on a regular `JPanel` as well.

`ButtonGroup` is a completely different concept in Swing then a `JPanel`. A `ButtonGroup` is for example used to group a set of `JRadioButtons`, and makes sure that only one radio button in that group can be selected at the time. But a `ButtonGroup` is not a `JComponent` nor a `Container`, so of course you will not find methods like `setBorder` on it.

Side-note: do not port those `setBounds` calls. Use a decent `LayoutManager` instead